# How to make boost.build use a specific compiler installation?

Tags: boost, compiler-construction

I am trying to build boost 1.45 using a local GCC compiler installation. I can't make it use a different compiler command that the default "g++". Here what happened so far:

In boost_1_45_0 source directory:

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=gcc --prefix=$INSTALL/boost-$TYPE
```

Then added the following line to "projct-config.jam":

using gcc : 4.4.6 : [absolute path]/install/gcc-4.4.6/bin/g++ : ;

```
./bjam install --prefix=$INSTALL/boost-$TYPE
```

When bringing up the process list during building, I can see that the system's default compiler command g++ gets used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a previous definition of **using** which got in the way. This solves the problem:

project-config.jam:

```
if ! gcc in [ feature.values <toolset> ]
{
    using gcc : 4.4.6 : [absolute path]/install/gcc-4.4.6/bin/g++ : -L[absolute path]/install/gcc-4.4.6/lib64 -I[absolute path]/install/gcc-4.4.6/include ;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That should be `toolset=gcc-4.4.6` rather than `--with-toolset=gcc` (features are not specified with leading dashes).